# Preg_replace improvement

Tags: php, regex

I would like to improve my preg_replace regex.
This is to clean a features list.

I want allow for the begining of each line:

- alphanumeric characters
- == and alphanumeric characters
- -- alphanumeric characters
- ++ alphanumeric characters
- ** alphanumeric characters

my regex:

```
$features = "
    == Category one
    → feature 1
    ++ feature 2
    -- feature 3
    ==-
    ! feature 4
    % feature 5";    

preg_replace('/' . 
          '^[^[:alnum:]]{0,}(==-.*)$' . '|' .              // ==-
          '^[^[:alnum:]]{0,}([\+|\-|\*|\=]{2}.*)$' . '|' . // ==
          '^[^[:alnum:]]{0,}(.*)$' .                       // abc
          '/mu', '$1$2$3', 
          $features);
```

Dirty features:

- == Category one
- → feature 1
- ++ feature 2
- -- feature 3
- ==-
- ! feature 4
- % feature 5

Clean:

- == Category one
- feature 1
- ++ feature 2
- -- feature 3
- ==-
- feature 4
- feature 5

It works, but i think there is a better way ...
Thanks

Comment: Is $features the entire string - or has it already been separated for each line? Based off what I see in your Regexp - it looks like the entire string is in there. You may be better off just exploding your string by line and then compare the first 2 to 3 characters using a switch statement which would be a little cheaper to process me thinks

Comment: Thanks a lot !
It's really easier !
I'm going to work on it, i would like it transform something like -line1 -- line2 to line1 -- line2
refuse +|-|=|* without whitespace after ...

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. Unfortunately, this reads like a "please help me write better code" - which is off topic, rather then "please explain what is wrong with this code so I can improve it" - which would be on-topic.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this one : `#^[^-=+*\w]{2}\s*#um` (that is [~500% faster](http://lumadis.be/regex/test_regex.php?id=1387) than yours):

```php
<?php
$list = '
== Category one
→ feature 1
++ feature 2
-- feature 3
==-
! feature 4
% feature 5
** feature 6
feature 7';

$list = preg_replace('#^[^-=+*\w]{2}\s*#um', '', $list);
print_r($list);
```

Whose output is:

```
== Category one
feature 1
++ feature 2
-- feature 3
==-
feature 4
feature 5
** feature 6
feature 7
```

### Subsidiary question

You can complete the regexp `#^[^-=+*\w]{2}\s*#um` by the regexp
`#^([-=+*])(?!\1|\s)#um` to refuse `+|-|=|*` without whitespace after.

It is possible to combine the two regexps but at the expense of performance.

```php
<?php
function printResult($label, $list, $start, $end) {
  printf(
    "%s: %F s\n%s\n\n",
    $label,
    $end - $start,
    print_r($list, true)
  );
}

$list = '== Category one
→ feature 1
++ feature 2
-- feature 3
==-
! feature 4
% feature 5
** feature 6
feature 7
-line1
-- line2';

// Case 1: regrouping the regexps
$time_start = microtime(true);
$list = preg_replace('#^[^-=+*\w]{2}\s*|^([-=+*])(?!\1|\s)#um', '', $list);
$time_end = microtime(true);
printResult('With one regexp', $list, $time_start, $time_end);

// Case 2: a faster way
$time_start = microtime(true);
$list = preg_replace('#^[^-=+*\w]{2}\s*#um', '', $list);
$list = preg_replace('#^([-=+*])(?!\1|\s)#um', '', $list);
$time_end = microtime(true);
printResult('In two pass, a faster way', $list, $time_start, $time_end);
```

Whose output is:

```
With one regexp: 0.000151 s
== Category one
feature 1
++ feature 2
-- feature 3
==-
feature 4
feature 5
** feature 6
feature 7
line1
-- line2

In two pass, a faster way: 0.000024 s
== Category one
feature 1
++ feature 2
-- feature 3
==-
feature 4
feature 5
** feature 6
feature 7
line1
-- line2
```

---

Note: `preg_replace` replaces the overall catch, therefore it is useless to try to capture the full line.